# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'

Tags: c++

I am not sure what am I doing wrong in defining the function:

Code snippet:

```
// Constructing linear spaced vector with increment 
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> LinSpaced_withInc(T tBegin, T tEnd, T tInc)
{
    std::size_t N = 2*((std::size_t)((tEnd - tBegin)/tInc) +1);
    std::vector<T> xs(N);
    std::vector<T>::iterator x;
    T val;
    val = tBegin; 
    for (x = xs.begin(); x != xs.end(); ++x) {
        *x = val;
        val += tInc;
    }
    return xs;
}
```

I am making the call:

```
std::vector<int> dataveci2 = LinSpaced_withInc((int)96,(int)91,(int)-1);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The error you cite is not produced by the code shown. Your actual code mentions `double` in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. My apologies. In declaration, I had declared arguments as double.

Comment: Please correct the code, as it is not clear which arguments you are talking about.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. A vector of double is not compatible with a vector of int.

Comment: Note that `96`, `91`, and `-1` are already `int`s so there is no need to typecast them: `std::vector<int> dataveci2 = LinSpaced_withInc(96, 91, -1);` But if you do want to be explicit that the parameters should be `int` than it would be cleaner to use the template parameter explicitly rather than using template deduction: `std::vector<int> dataveci2 = LinSpaced_withInc<int>(96, 91, -1);`